# Blocked a frame with origin "http://video.sasads.com" from accessing a frame

Tags: javascript, jquery

while developing a website today I noticed something odd on the console. This is the second time I see this error message. I googled the website sasads.com and came up without any info. Website apparently is xml in nature and seems to be very suspicious.

The console error code is **Blocked a frame with origin "http://video.sasads.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.**

The website is php/jquery and utilizes the latest jquery distribution. I searched for sasads.com in the js folders but could not locate such string. the jquery that was blocked stated it was running in 1.7 so it must be loading it offsite somewhere.

browser used is chrome, server running latest php and mysql environment. I wasnt able to recreate the error, guess there is some kind of trigger or timer that is hidden.

Question, should I be worried that one of the potential script has some sort of trojan or malware attached to it?

Comment: Sounds like an ad server to me.

Comment: The error is regarding the same-origin policy, but what did you do to get it?

Comment: Yvette: Link is of the actual error message from the console.

Comment: watson: Browser was idle when the error occurred, the error could not be reproduced as I could not find the trigger for it.

Comment: Webpage has no video or ads loaded.

Comment: @JIMJI1005 Did you ever figure out what this is? Exact same thing just happened to me today.

Comment: figured out any solution ?

Comment: I get the same issue. I have a feeling it is related to a Chrome plugin. Too bad Andrew Barber erroneously closed this bug by incorrectly assuming it was some sort of code mistake from the original author.

Comment: Same thing happened to me just now, this should not have been closed

Comment: I see this too on some content, please reopen.

Comment: @MBHNYC it's now reopened.

Comment: I highly suspect it's the "Webpage & WebCam Screenshot" extension. Can anyone corroborate?

Comment: Agree that an extn is the most likely culprit here. sasads is sitting on an Amazon AWS server. Playing about with a few urls, it seems to serving up some minified JS that loads player.sasads.com/swf/v4/liverail.swf - Liverail is a video ad inserter AFAIK, but I thought it tended to run from its own servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my experimenting, I believe this is caused by the "Edit This Cookie" extension.

Also: The reviews for the extension have similar complaints about ads.

Answer (score 1):

I just very unexpectedly had my Chrome browser switch from my ebay window to a new full-page advertisement; in researching more about what happened, I found this stack overflow question through my google search regarding the website that it jumped to. I'm leaving the following information for others who may be searching for issues with "sasads.com", "adverstitial.com", "openadserve", or "adlegend.com" -- they all seem to be culprits in the hijacking of my web browser (and should be banned, blocked, blacklisted, and otherwise removed from the 'Interwebs').

In response to the Original Poster's error, I believe that the browser you were using tried to do the same exact jump to an "adverstitial.com" page. This page then has a script that loads content from "sasads.com", and you were seeing an error in how it loads.

I was able to capture the javascript from the site, and yes - it has a timer on it after which it tries to go back to the site you were originally on. Thus, you wouldn't have been able to see it. I have much more information about this and captured the javascript that was run. I haven't figured out where it was triggered yet. I only have one Chrome extension (Session Manager). I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error in Chrome. In my case, it started after installing the PageRank Status extension.

Comment: Please use the comment section, do not post comments in the answer